# multiple inserts not working with mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert six records in a table, but when the script runs I get the following

> error: 'Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter by reference'.

See the code below for the specific line:

```php
$ySQL = "SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM USUARIOS WHERE EMAIL=?";
$stmt = $oConni->prepare($ySQL) or die($oConni->error);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $datos[8]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($idUsuario);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

for($i=1;$i<7;$i++){
   $vSQL = "INSERT INTO PERMISOS (ID_USUARIO,ID_ACCION,PERMISOS) VALUES(?,?,?)";
   $stmt = $oConni->prepare($vSQL) or die($oConni->error);

   // ERROR. The following line throws it:
   $stmt->bind_param('iis', $idUsuario, $i, 'S');
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Please always specify the line in which the error occurs.

Comment: @ComFreek the error is here -> $stmt->bind_param('iis', $idUsuario, $i, 'S'); 

'S' is a field type 'ENUM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`'s signature:

> bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed
>   &$... ] )

As you can see, the method accepts all parameters – except the first one – as references.

You need at least a variable or a function's return value for having a reference. You cannot use a *String Literal* like `'S'`.

Here is a fix:

```
$str = 'S';
$stmt->bind_param('iis', $idUsuario, $i, $str);
```